# Get data for mail body: phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'd like to send mails via phpmailer and I'd like to get the name from the database for mail body with looping, but my code doesn't work. It keeps on getting the same name for every single mail. Here's my code:

```
<?php  //Library require("phpmailer/classes/class.phpmailer.php");

//Database
$server = "localhost";
$username = "mydatabase_admin";
$password = "localadmin123";
$database = "mydatabase";

//Connect to database
$dbConnection = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

//Check connection
if ($dbConnection -> connect_error) {
    echo "Connection Failed";
    die ($dbConnection -> connect_error);
}

//Select database and data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM userdata";
$result = $dbConnection -> query($sql);

//Mailing
//Sender information
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
//Use SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//SMTP Server
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
//SMTP Account
$mail->Username = "my_mail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "********";

//Automated Mail
$mail->SetFrom('tphp43598@gmail.com', 'Admin');

//Recipient info
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    { 
        $mail->AddAddress($row["Email"]);
        $mail->Subject = "Product Review Reminder";
        $mail->Body = "Hi ". $row["Full Name"] .",". "\n \nJust a reminder that you need to review the product coded ". $row["Product Handled"] . ".\n" . "Thank You";
    }
}

//Output shown                         if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Message was not sent.';
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "\n" . 'Message has been sent.';
} ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. Which one is your question?

Comment: Take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). It does what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    { 
        $mail->AddAddress($row["Email"]);
        $mail->Subject = "Product Review Reminder";
        $mail->Body = "Hi ". $row["Full Name"] .",". "\n \nJust a reminder that you need to review the product coded ". $row["Product Handled"] . ".\n" . "Thank You";
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo 'Message was not sent.';
            echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo "\n" . 'Message has been sent.';
        } 
    }
}
```

You are calling sendmail() function outside while loop you are getting name variable whichever is last record. keep inside while loop.

Or if you need to track each individual mail send status then keep array of status. Keep pushing message into status array.

Comment: One major issue with this is that you are not clearing any existing to addresses each time around the loop; call `clearAddresses()` after `send()`; otherwise you'll end up sending many duplicates and have many annoyed recipients. Setting `$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;` will make sending much faster.